# I am a US citizen and want to move to Germany with my husband who is a EU citizen of the UK. Do I require a residence or spouse visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, us-citizens, resident-permit, eu-spouses

I want to make sure I'm applying for the right visa.
I am a US citizen who has been married to a EU citizen from the UK for almost a month now. We plan to move to Germany together and plan to reside there for a long while. What do we need to do? Would I be applying for a residence permit to join him in Germany?

Comment: You do not need a visa.  You can apply for the residence card after arriving in Germany.  You should do that within 90 days of your arrival.